# How to mouse hover on top of below span element in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to mouse hover on top of below span element with value ' Get Special Access'. But unable to succeed with the same since there are dual span elements within the same.

HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-active" id="menuitem-1935" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 25px; margin: 0px; width: 250px;">
<a id="menuitem-1935-itemEl" class="x-menu-item-link" href="#" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on">
<div role="img" id="menuitem-1935-iconEl" class="x-menu-item-icon  " style="">
</div>
<span id="menuitem-1935-textEl" class="x-menu-item-text" unselectable="on">
<span class="menu_item_head">Access</span> Get Special Access</span>
<img id="menuitem-1935-arrowEl" src="ext-4.2.1.883/resources/themes/images/default/tree/s.gif" class="x-menu-item-arrow">
</a>
</div>
```

I did try with below,

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath("//span[.= ' Get Special Access']"))).perform();
```

and ended up with error:

```
 Message:
   Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[.= ' Get Special Access'])
 Stack:
   NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //span[.= ' Get Special Access])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using one of the following locators: 
`element(by.xpath("//*[@id='menuitem-1935-textEl']"))`
`element(by.xpath("//*[@id='menuitem-1935-textEl']//span"))`

Comment: The Id's are auto generated values. Hence, I'm preferring for the text within the span.